# Can using PCManFM rather than Nautilus/Files in 18.04 cause problems?

Tags: nautilus, 18.04, pcmanfm

I've installed the 3rd-party light file manager PCManFM 1.2.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 because Nautilus/Files was frustrating me (over-simplicity & seeming absence of some features).

So far I've been liking it much better, but I was running through Ubuntu configuration suggestions and [warnings on this seemingly-intelligent site](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/fatalmistakes#TOC-Don-t-install-a-second-full-blown-file-manager) when I found this warning:

> **Don't install a second full-blown file manager**
>
> 5.1. Related to the "don't mix desktop environments" issue: completely replacing your default file manager by another, will almost certainly
>   lead to a disastrous mess: the removal of the default file manager
>   might even make your desktop unusable.
>
> It's not even advisable to install a full-blown second file manager
>   next to your default one. It's best to stick to the file manager that
>   comes by default with your desktop environment, and leave it at that.
>
> The reason is, that full-blown file managers are deeply interwoven
>   with the desktop environment for which they were designed. They're the
>   backbone of the desktop. That means that they can cause problems after
>   installation in a "foreign" desktop environment: they simply engrain
>   themselves too deeply in that "foreign" desktop and tend to clash
>   sometimes with its primary file manager.
>
> Exceptions are stand-alone simple file managers like Double Commander
>   and Midnight Commander. They don't interweave themselves with the
>   desktop environment at all, and only do their primary limited task:
>   basic file management.

So I'm wondering if PCManFM is going to cause me misery at some point, or if it is light (and/or Ubuntu-approved) enough not to be a worry?

Comment: IDK about running PCManFM on GNOME desktop, but Nautilus was annoying enough to be a factor in my installing the LXDE desktop which is built around PCManFM. I've never looked back! So now my default config is to install Ubuntu then install LXDE and use it exclusively. Give it a try if you like PCManFM!  (This is different from installing just Lubuntu, although that uses PCManFM as well).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not cause problems.  PCManFM and other similar lightweight file managers (Thunar etc) do not integrate into the OS.  They keep to themselves and store their own separate settings and configuration files.

The link you posted talks about "Full blown file managers", which I believe is talking about something like Nautilus or Dolphin.  These are much larger file managers which do much more with the OS.

I have installed Dolphin before on a system that used Nautilus.  While it didn't really cause problem, it did make of mess of package installs because installing Dolphin on a Gnome system also installs many many KDE and Qt packages.  These files could conflict with Gnome and may cause problems if they both try to accomplish the same task, like mounting inserted devices.  It's also more difficult to remove because of the large amount of dependencies that comes with it.  Lightweight file managers like PCManFM have very few dependencies from desktops.

The worst conflicts of the past were installing both Gnome and Unity, which is no longer an issue.  It's best to keep the 3 major desktops and their dependencies apart if possible.